# Formatting string to html angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am trying to do something as follows, and I have no idea where to start looking it up even.

I am trying to create some object such as this

```
{ 
 text: "hello {param1}", 
 param1: {
              text:"world", 
              class: "bla"
         }
}
```

The thing is I want to display it according to the text property like this:

```
<span> hello <span class="bla"> world </span></span>
```

Using a component for such thing won't really solve it - the only idea I have is using jquery, and I would like to avoid it. The text property format could be changed if it helps...

Comment: How do you want to use it within angular2 component?

Comment: I want it to be more kinda generic, it's hard to explain.. 
In WPF you could define a DataTemplate to the param1 object, and by using some mad WPF skills make this work in the ViewModel (kinda WPF's Component equivilent) by just binding to this object in the view.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not really possible in angular 2 however, so anything that does not require me to use arrays and a very ugly implementation would make me grateful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you an idea like this:

```
import { Component, Directive, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: 'my-template'
})
class MyTemplate {
  @Input() data: Object;
  @HostBinding('innerHTML') get html {
    return Object.keys(this.data).reduce((prev, cur) => {
      if(cur === 'text') return prev;
      const regExp = new RegExp(`{${cur}}`, 'g');
      return prev.replace(regExp, (str) =>{
        return `<${this.data[cur].tag} class="${this.data[cur].class}">
                  ${this.data[cur].text}
                </${this.data[cur].tag}>`; 
      });
    }, this.data.text);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-template [data]="obj"></my-template>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [MyTemplate] 
})
export class App {
  obj = { 
    text: "hello {param1} {param2} please again hello {param1}", 
    param1: {
      tag: 'span',
      text: 'world', 
      class: 'bla'
    },
    param2: {
      tag: 'div',
      text: 'hello world2', 
      class: 'bla'
    }
  };
}
```

See example in action here http://plnkr.co/edit/G5m7zAxzhybhN5QdnVik?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be like this :
In your component class :

```
let myConfig = {
  salutation : "hello",
  paramText : "world",
  paramClass : "bla"
}
```

And in your HTML :

```
<span> {{myConfig.salution}} <span class="{{myConfig.paramClass}}"> {{myConfig.paramText}} </span></span>
```

Then you could just swap the values of myConfig properties to generate text with the specified class for the paramText accordingly. Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I am looking for something a bit more generic.. allowing for more params and neater implementation. Anyway this seems like an Idea I could use to fit my needs, by using arrays, anyway it would be ugly...